# My machine boots into tty1 and it won't let me type anything

Tags: boot

I have a Dell XPS 15, I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS yesterday, no dual boot. Last thing I remember is removing `quiet splash` from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`.

Now, next thing I know, I can't boot into ubuntu. I am met with a tty1 screen, which basically does nothing. I can literally type nothing. It just says

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS MYNAME-MYMACHINENAME ttyl
MYNAME-MYMACHINENAME login:
```

No blinking cursor, nothing. No ctrl+alt+f-key combination works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to type your username, hit Enter, type your password and hit Enter again? Did anything happen?

Comment: Yup, multiple times. I did all sorts of combinations of that. Still nothing.

Comment: The Dell XPS 15 has an high-end Nvidia card. The *"removing quiet splash"* suggests you were trying to troubleshoot a no video / hang on boot situation but in a **very wrong way**. You don't need to remove "quiet splash" but you do need `nomodeset` added to the same line until you install the recommended Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @MichaelBay Yeah, unfortunately I realized that when it was too late. I just installed Ubuntu yesterday. I have nothing saved on it....should I just reinstall?

Comment: If you can access the Grub menu you can easily add the parameter the same way you removed the other. Then it will boot in low graphics mode but everything else should work and enable you to graphically install the required drivers. But of course reinstalling is an option, just keep in mind what you need to do.